# I cannot get afterLoad to work in FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <a rel="group" href="images/reveal.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor." class="fancybox"><img src="images/images3.jpg"></a>
    <a rel="group" href="images/reveal2.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor." class="fancybox"><img src="images/images1.jpg"></a>
    <a rel="group" href="images/reveal3.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor." class="fancybox"><img src="images/images2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {
            this.inner.append('<p>TEST</p>');
            this.content = '<p>TEST2</p>' + this.content.html();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

With the above, I get an error in Firebug: "this.inner is undefined."

I'm clearly missing something, but I've been staring at this too long to see what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the suggestions.

I tried every one of them, to no avail. I ended up ditching the method I was trying to use, and am simply going to call a div, and style my content in there.

The end result will look something like the HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/NjNMC/. The JS in that example won't be used; that's what started this whole mess.

Comment: You havent added fabcybox to your jsFiddle cdn for fabcybox: http://yandex.st/jquery/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this.inner.append('<p>TEST</p>');` try `$(this).html('<p>TEST</p>');`

Answer (score 2):

This is an year old question, but this might be of help to someone who is searching..

Try using "`beforeShow`" callback that gets called right before opening animation starts..

[more info here](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/254)..

Comment: `beforeShow` worked for me – allowed me to remove a great deal of ugly code waiting for existence of a loaded-in element... `afterShow` just didn't seem to work as it was supposed to

Answer (score 0):

You probabbly want to inject this html in the fancybox window.
you are not referring to that with te keyword `this`, try `$('#fancybox-outer')` 
Note that this is undocumented use.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {
            $(".fancybox")[0].inner.append('<p>TEST</p>');
            //$(".fancybox")[0].content = '<p>TEST2</p>' + $(".fancybox")[0].content.html();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
     openEffect: 'none',
     closeEffect: 'none',
     afterLoad: function () {
         this.outer.prepend('<a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logoShow"></a>');
         this.outer.append('<div id="btnExpand"><img src="img/nav_menu_expand.png" input type="submit"/></div>');
     }
 });
```